# JRE 7 Update 55 Security Warning checkbox

Tags: java, security, applet

Loading an applet after installing JRE 7 update 55 I get a "Security Warning" dialog.

I check the checkbox for 
"Do not show this again for this app and web site" and click on "Allow". The applet loads.

[image]

However if i navigate away from the applet and load it again, the dialog comes up again. It is as if it does not remember the checkbox option.

The  Caller-Allowable-Codebase is set to * in the applets manifest file because the app needs to be deployed on any server designated by our client.

Is this a jre u55 bug? or is there something that needs to be done to make that checkbox functional?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle encourages you use signed applets to enhance security. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html.

Comment: That screenshot is just an example of the dialog. The applet that I am loading is signed legitimately.

Comment: This behaviour occurs also with JRE 1.7.0_65-b19

Comment: @user3142812 Did you solved this? I have the same problem!